# What does it mean by "Your Page' post is performing better than 95% posts.." on Facebook pages

Tags: facebook

What does it mean by `'Your Page's post is performing better than 95% other posts on that page. Promote it to get even better results.` notification mean on Facebook pages? It keeps appearing one or two days after we post something on our Facebook page.

1. Is it just promotional trick of Facebook? Or it really gets triggered when this event occurs?
2. How do they calculate this value-"95%"?
3. Does it usually make more impressions to promote posts (as sponsored content) at 95% level? Or, from the beginning? Or, doesn't matter? Why specifically mention this 95%?

Answer (score 2):

Only Facebook knows the answers - and I suspect they're not telling.

But from my observations, I do not think the "95%" is calculated, and I do think it's a marketing trick.

Comment: Agreed. I get it on far more than 5% of my posts, and on quite a few which are clearly not doing better than most of the others.

Answer (score 0):

You post seen 95% more compared other posts on your page, its facebook new feature thats tell you will post engage more people on your page.

Answer (score 0):

When I get that message from Facebook concerning my business page, it's always in reference to a post which I know is one of the more popular ones, so the report seems at least semi-accurate.

The only odd, buggy thing, is that when I click on that message from Facebook to see the post in question, the error message ALWAYS comes up, *Page not found.*  The first time I saw that message, my heart sank - I thought maybe that post had somehow disappeared.  But no, the posts Facebook refers to this way are still there, but the links they're sending me about the posts aren't programmed correctly - they're always dead links.